# page scroll not working in wordpress menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

been battling with this for some time...

I have a bootstrap menu with smooth scrolling. the a tag is page-scroll in the HTML but this does not translate over to the WP menu in the php. heres my code for a typical link.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#one">Free 30 minute web audit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
```

the menu in my header has been replaced with

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav page-scroll ',
        ) ); 
            ?>
```

Functions file has the following.

```
<?php

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' )

);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' ); 

?>
```

Some help would be fantastic. Alex

Comment: You have to extend the Walker_Nav_Menu class and implement your own menu. Check this article about the [Walker class in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) . Then simply add 'walker' => new Your_Walker_Class to the array in wp_nav_menu function.

Comment: dude i am really struggling to get my head around this... could you be a bit more specific on how i register the page-scroll a class to my menu.